# How to change Microsoft Chart Control minimum and maximum values?

Tags: .net, winforms, charts, mschart, microsoft-chart-controls

All my values lie between 1.5 and 1.6 but the Chart Control draws the chart to fit values from 0 to 2. As the result the chart looks pretty ugly and hardly readable:

[image]

How to make it to display more adequately? I haven't managed to find any properties responsible for setting the domain. Would be cool if I could configure the control to figure out the minimum and the maximum automatically but setting them manually would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by setting the following properties of the `ChartAreas`

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 1.5;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1.6;
```